# Bash still trying to use uninstalled and unlinked Vim version

Tags: bash, macos, vim, homebrew, iterm2

I am trying to switch to vim 8. I uninstalled 7.4 and install 8 with homebrew. I am currently stuck with the following error:

```
$ vim
-bash: /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1301/bin/vim: No such file or directory
```

I don't understand what is happening because the linkings seems correct:

```
$ which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
$ readlink /usr/local/bin/vim
../Cellar/vim/8.0.0051/bin/vim
```

I am using iTerm2 as my terminal and I already tried restarting it.

Edit 1: For the installation I removed vim completely using brew uninstall vim and then reinstalled it through homebrew.

Edit 2:
`$ brew info vim
vim: stable 8.0.0051 (bottled), HEAD
Vi "workalike" with many additional features
http://www.vim.org/
Conflicts with: ex-vi
/usr/local/Cellar/vim/8.0.0051 (1,710 files, 23.3M) *
  Poured from bottle on 2016-10-28 at 11:24:37`

Edit 3: brew cleanup also did not yield a result.

Comment: might be better to also add which commands did you use to uninstall?

Comment: Looks like an homebrew issue.

Comment: Try running `hash -r` and start `vim` again.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I tried this but there is no new entry in the hash table after running vim again. The error is the same.

Comment: there might be an alias or function or whatever... try `type -a vim`

Comment: @ZabojCampula Through the command I found an alias in a dotfile that I had missed. Removing it and restarting iTerm resolved the issue. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Shell aliases / functions may still apply. The `which` command doesn't see those.

You can check with

```
$ type vim
vim is aliased to `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.1301/bin/vim'
```

Or try invoking Vim with quotes:

```
$ 'vim'
```